# how NFA implement negate regex

Tags: regex, nfa

I try to use NFA to implement a negate regex.

I know that NFA can easily combine regex like `ab` `a|b` and `a*`

and the variety `[ab]` can convert to `a|b`

but how can I convert `[^ab]` to a NFA fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a character class.  The transitions of NFAs are labeled with single characters or lambda (the empty string).  To implement a character class, just have a transition for each character in the class.  The negated class is just implemented with one transition for each character *not* in the class.  Since the NFA is required to have a finite alphabet, this is no problem at all.  If A is the alphabet and you want [^ab], then you need one transition for each character in the set A - {a, b}.

Comment: that's a good idea, but it means that when the NFA receive a char, it will foreach every the transfer of the state. actually, I implements a transfer just using a data struct like multiMap, it will find the next states by hash of the character, and in most case, it's faster than foreach transfers in the state.

Comment: Production scanners usually encode character classes either as an array of state numbers, one element per character or, if the class is simple, a sorted list of intervals.   But then production scanners don't use NFAs because they're quite a bit slower than DFAs.